# Agrandar Imagen al dar click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cordial Saludo,

Espero me puedan ayudar con lo que intento hacer.

Lo que hago es, tengo un input de tipo file `<input type"file">` y lo que hace es cargar una imagen y mostrar la preview de la img, hasta acá vamos bien, lo que deseo hacer despues, es que la preview de la imagen al darle click, se agrande en pantalla completa, como un modal o algo así.

Tengo una prueba con una imagen ya con una ruta y funciona perfectamente, pero asi como quiero no funciona.

Estilos:

```
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Script que hace el preview

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){

 $(function() {
  $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
      addImage(e); 
     });

     function addImage(e){
      var file = e.target.files[0],
      imageType = /image.*/;

      if (!file.type.match(imageType))
       return;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = fileOnload;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }

     function fileOnload(e) {
      var result=e.target.result;
      $('#imgSalida').attr("src",result);
     }
    });
  });

</script>

   <input name="file-input" id="file-input" type="file" />
   <br />
   <img id="imgSalida" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" src="" />
   <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img012">
  <div id="caption2"></div>
</div>
```

Script que utilizo para darle click y agrandarla:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

De esta forma no me funciona, pero si llegara a usar una img por defecto si funciona, pero no es el caso.

Espero me entiendan lo que deseo hacer y me puedan ayudar..

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿ Creo que lo que tratas de hacer es algo como esto ? en caso de ser me cuentas y hago una version en jQuery! Saludos!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const imgInput = document.getElementById('image');
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    const plusButton = document.querySelector('.plus');
    const minusButton = document.querySelector('.minus');


    imgInput.addEventListener('change', setImage);
    plusButton.addEventListener('click', increaseSize);
    minusButton.addEventListener('click', reduceSize);
    img.addEventListener('click', fullScreen);


    function setImage() {
        img.file = this.files[0];
        img.classList.add('imageLoaded');
        container.appendChild(img);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (img) {
            return function (e) {
                img.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
    
    function increaseSize() {
        img.style.width = `${img.width += 100}px`;
        img.style.height = `${img.height += 50}px`;
    }

    function reduceSize() {
        if (img.width <= 100 || img.height <= 50) return;
        img.style.width = `${img.width -= 100}px`;
        img.style.height = `${img.height -= 50}px`;
    }
    
    function fullScreen() {
        if (this.width === window.innerWidth) {
            img.style.width = (window.innerWidth / 2) + "px";
        } else {
            img.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
}

.imageLoaded {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<input id="image" type="file" placeholder="Load an image">
<br>
<button class="plus">+</button>
<button class="minus">-</button>
<br>
<div class="container">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, a base de esto, pude hacer lo que necesito

Comment: Encantado colega!